# dropbox folder share with other dropbox user .Net

Tags: .net, dropbox

I have uploaded file into dropbox folder using API. The folders are also created dynamically.

Now I want to share the folder with another dropbox user.

Please help how to proceed with the API call using .Net

Comment: You would use [ShareFolderAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingRoutes_ShareFolderAsync_1.htm) to share the folder, and [AddFolderMemberAsync](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingRoutes_AddFolderMemberAsync_1.htm) to invite members. Have you tried implementing those? If so, update your question with whatever issues you're running in to.

Comment: Hi Greg, I tried to use ShareFolderAsync &  AddFolderMemberAsync but I am not able to understand what parameters I should pass. SharedFolderAsync expects memberPolicy which says current user is on a team. So where will I pass the email to whome I need to give access to folder. Moreover in second method it asks for Shared folder Id, but my folder is not shared one, I need to share it. Do you have any code snippet which can help me

Comment: I don't have a good code sample for this available, unfortunately. Can you update your post with that you have so far and what you're stuck on? For what it's worth though, `memberPolicy` is optional, so I would leave that out for now. And in your case you will need to call `ShareFolderAsync` before `AddFolderMemberAsync`, in order to make sure the folder is shared already, and get the shared folder ID.